# Trouble targeting siblings

Tags: jquery, dom, tree, traversal

Hi I have an unordered list:

```
<ul class="prodDetails">
<li class="details1"><a href="">Link1</a></li>
<li class="details2"><a href="">Link2</a></li>
<li class="details3"><a href="">Link3</a></li>
</ul>

$("ul.prodDetails li.details1 a").addClass('prodDetailsOn').siblings().removeClass('prodDetailsOn');
```

I am trying to add the class "prodDetailsOn" to the href that is clicked, while removing it from all of the other hrefs.

I'm missing the target somehow. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to go back to the `<li>` element to get the other LI's.

```
$("ul.prodDetails li.details1 a").addClass('prodDetailsOn').parent('li').siblings().removeClass('prodDetailsOn');
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer, since it keeps the local scope corrected, whereas the others require additional lookups.

Comment: Thanks. This didn't *quite* work but it helped me figured it out. I added find("a") and it worked: $("ul.prodDetails li.details3 a").addClass('prodDetailsOn').parent('li').siblings().find("a").removeClass('prodDetailsOn');

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a common pattern. What I do is first remove the toggle and then set it on the thing, that triggered the event.

```
$('.prodDetails a').click(function () {
    $('.prodDetails a.prodDetailsOn').removeClass('prodDetailsOn');
    $(this).addClass('prodDetailsOn');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul li a").click(function() {
$("ul li a").removeClass("propDetailsOn");
$(this).addClass('propDetailsOn');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
$("a").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    $("a").not($(this)).removeClass("prodDetailsOn");
    $(this).addClass("prodDetailsOn");
});
});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/uF7M5/1/